# Remove shadow effect from text in powerpoint 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to remove all the shadow effects from all the textframes in the any slides of the presentation via a macro . 
The below macro is running well with powerpoint 2007 but not working with 2010.

```
Sub NoTextShadows()

    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oShp As Shape

    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
            If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Shadow = msoFalse
                    oShp.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
                End If
            End If
        Next oShp
    Next oSld

End Sub
```

Please suggest any idea to workaround this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I made some tests and I found out that shadows in PowerPoint 2010 can appear for Text (for specific) and for shapes in general. It's strange that two shadows can be applied to the shape independently, but only one of them could be removed by Macro. Here is what I did to remove one layer of shadow :

```
oShp.Shadow.Size = 0
OShp.Shadow.Blur = 0
oShp.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
```

Try adding these lines inside your main For Loop and see

For more information, [Working with Properties of the ShadowFormat Class in Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh273478%28v=office.14%29.aspx)